# How to extract the containers in Mission 21 War Economy?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

One of the tasks is to extract the 3 containers in the North Hangar of the airport. With the containers under a roof, Fulton extract fails. What needs to be done to extract these containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will eventually be able to upgrade your Fulton with a "Wormhole Generator". Wormhole Fultons aren't affected by Weather or roofs since the target is physically teleported; the added benefit being near-instant recovery.

As shown in this [official preview](https://youtu.be/OGGuvRIIx8c?t=19m1s)

Comment: Again making me wonder why I can't Fulton extract myself from a mission, rather than having to manually run out of the hot zone.

Comment: @Sterno Well, you can if you're on top of a materials container!

Comment: @RavenDreamer But not with the wormhole fulton!

Comment: @Maurycy False! I've done it, wormholes and all!

Comment: @RavenDreamer Oh? When I tried to wormhole fulton a container while standing on it I just fell down to the ground once the animation finished :(.

Comment: @Maurycy. When you Fulton extract a container while on top of it, you need to hold on so you don't fall down. How to do it is indicated by an icon drawn on the HUD.